# How to get value from HSSFComments in apache POI

Tags: java, apache

I want to read/extract the value from HSSFComment.
I can access the HSSFComment by the following code:

```
HSSFComment comment = workSheet.getCellComment(1, 0);
```

But, how can I get the text/value from that "comment" instance?

there are tow methods in HSSFComment:

```
getTextObjectRecord() 
getNoteRecord()
```

But both are protected methods...that's why I can't access those from my class. in other word, these methods are not visible from my class. Following line of code doesn't compile.

```
TextObjectRecord txo = comment.getTextObjectRecord();
```

Any comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getString()` inherited from `HSSFTextBox`. This returns an `HSSFRichTextString`, which itself has a `getString()` method to get the plain text.  In otherwords

```
String comment = cell.getComment().getString().getString();
```

Which you can't do like that due to the possibility of `null` returns, but that's the idea.